# From where can I download the WMD editor?

Tags: editor, wmd, wmd-editor

I would like to add WMD editor to my website, but I do not find the source code of it anywhere. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the function **makeSpritedButtonRow** in ***wmd.js*** fils (around line 913).

Let us say if you do not want the boldButton then comment the lines containing the "boldButton".

Example:

```
        var boldButton = document.createElement("li");
        boldButton.className = "wmd-button";
        boldButton.id = "wmd-bold-button";
        boldButton.title = "Strong <strong> Ctrl+B";
        boldButton.XShift = "0px";
        boldButton.textOp = command.doBold;
        setupButton(boldButton, true);
        buttonRow.appendChild(boldButton);
```

comment all the above line and your boldButton is gone.......

I have downloaded my copy of WMD [here](https://github.com/derobins/wmd).

Answer (score 2):

The original project is; http://code.google.com/p/wmd/ (dead main site).
There is also the [Stack Overflow version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103899/is-the-complete-so-rendering-js-available-uncompressed) here; http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I downloaded the source code now. I do not need few buttons like the Code sample,Block Quote,Image etc.  How do I remove those buttons. Can you help me?

Comment: Both `http://code.google.com/p/wmd/` and `http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/` are broken now (404) (Google Code shutdown 2016-01-15). Perhaps update?